# in postgresql how to get the last 4 numbers from a field and copy it to a new field

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I'm trying to get the last four digits of the field "SERIAL8" and put that in a new field called "SS4".  Here is the query I'm trying to use but it isn't working.  I'm new at this, so any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
SUBSTRING (SERIAL,4,4) as 'SS4'




CUSTOMER_TABLE
+-----------------------+------------+----------+--+
| "Complaint Full Date" |   Source   |  SERIAL  |  |
+-----------------------+------------+----------+--+
| 02/04/16              | DAPIS_CAIR | DG540732 |  |
| 04/18/16              | DAPIS_CAIR | DG553384 |  |
| 03/23/17              | RO         | DG559515 |  |
| 03/29/16              | CAIR       | DG559781 |  |
| 12/10/14              | DAPIS_CAIR | DG561621 |  |
+-----------------------+------------+----------+--+
```

Comment: `right(last8, 4)`?

Comment: Digits only or any characters?

Comment: @eurotrash -- it could be any digit or characters

Comment: Greemplum or Postgres? Although they share the same roots, they are sufficiently different that you shouldn't add both tags. But what's wrong with `right(.., 4)`?

Comment: It is Greenplum.  When I use the RIGHT function, I get an error that says RIght function does not exist.  I'm beginning to think greenplum doesnt have the RIGHT function

Comment: @rsajdak Does SUBSTRING work? If so: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Q5quAKyfuxBnWWjUUfpKQ/0